# UITextField and UITextView - stuck

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview, freeze

I'm using UITextField and UITextView in Xcode to edit the text by user (iPhone application). UItextField is for "Name" and UITextView for some "Notes". Everythink works great, but when I edit first field and than click on the second field, everything is going to freeze. (User edit name and than he/she wants to edit notes... -> freeze).

Thank you in advance for any advice.

EDIT:

I'm using hidding the keyboard by sliding and when I put this function away, it works... And I have found this (Maybe something wrong here?):

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x27cc3c58)

```
#pragma mark - Internal Methods 
- (void)reAssignFirstResponder
{
   // Find first responder
   UIView *inputView = [self findFirstResponder];
   if (inputView != nil) {
   // Re assign the focus
   [inputView resignFirstResponder];
   [inputView becomeFirstResponder];
  }
}
```

Comment: Pause the app when it freezes - what are the threads doing?

Comment: @MitsBhadeshiya
I have just edited my question with details.

Answer (score 1):

These 2 lines are resigning and assigning to the same field

```
[inputView resignFirstResponder];
[inputView becomeFirstResponder];
```

You are going to get into a loop, the `becomeFirstResponder` needs to be a different field

Why do you need code to handle responders?

Comment: Oh, ok. I "just" need to hide the keyboard with slide down and I don't know other methods. Is it possible to get out of the loop (easily :-) )?

Comment: have you tried removing the second line `[inputView becomeFirstResponder]`

Comment: Yes. After that, keyboard disappears after sliding down, but when I click on the second field -> keyboard will hide and the screen freeze (but not like before, now I can go back with Back Button in the top bar).

And when I remove the second line, everything works, but the keyboard will not disappear after sliding down.

Comment: Without you posting more code in your original question its going to be difficult to see what you are trying to achieve. You say that the keyboard disappears and then won't disappear after sliding down? That doesn't describe the issue. If you remove your method completely and don't call it does the keyboard work how you want it too?

Comment: If I remove the method [inputView becomeFirstResponder] it is better than before. Keyboard works how I would like to. One small problem is, that I'm editing first field (e.g. name) and than click on the second field (e.g. notes) -> screen looks like frozen (I'm not able scroll up and down and I'm not able to write more text...), but buttons in the top bar (Back button) works. Btw. thank you for your willingness, it's hard with me.

Comment: no I meant remove this method `- (void)reAssignFirstResponder` and all the code in it completely and don't call it